# want to get id of the selected dropdown list name php

Tags: php

I have 2 tables, `Cover` and `Book`.

Cover:

```
id            number,
Case_name     varchar(20)
```

(Case_name entries in database table: good, bad, none)

Book:

```
id            number,
Book_name     varchar2(20),
Cover         number
```

I have a form for book:

```
<div class="row-form" style="margin-top: -19px;">
  <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 06px">Book_name:</div>
  <div class="span9"><input type="text" name="bookname"/></div>
</div>

<div>

<select name='cstatus' style="width: 100%;">;

<?php
$user = "fyp";
$pass = "fyp";
$host = "localhost/CRMP";

// Connection with the Oracle.
$con = oci_connect($user, $pass, $host);

// Prepares an Oracle statement for execution.
$query = oci_parse($con,"SELECT id, Case_name FROM Cover");

// Executes a statement.                                                                           oci_execute($query);

while($row = oci_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['Case_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
 </select>
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the selected name(good,bad,none) and not the name in my database. like

```
Cover Table:
------------
id       Case_name
1        good
2        bad
3        none

Book table:
----------
id        booK_Name          Cover
1         Alp                1(not the name "good")
```

Comment: Look into using a [`JOIN` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: remember to call `oci_execute()` after `oci_parse()`